# Problem checking if any words in a list contain a partial string .net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm using C# .net and I'm getting NullReferenceException at this point:

```
Request.Params.AllKeys.Any(l => l.Contains("stringImLookingFor"));
```

used this on debug and `"stringImLookingFor"` is a constant (so is never `null`):

```
var aux = Request; 
var aux2 = Request.Params; 
var aux3 = Request.Params.AllKeys;
```

And none of this was `null`. I guess the problem is because  `l.Contains("stringImLookingFor")` returns `null`. Any idea how to fix it??

Thx.

Comment: stick a breakpoint on that line, and check to see if Request, Params or AllKeys is null...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because one of the following is null:

- Request
- Request.Params
- Request.Params.AllKeys
- l (used at l.Contains(). This would occur if you'd managed to get a null key in there somehow)

You can't tell which from the single liner though. Either stick on a breakpoint and check them manually, or add a check in code to see if each is null.

Update:

Would recommend

```
Request.Params.AllKeys.Any(l => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l) &&
                           l.Contains("stringImLookingFor"));
```

Comment: used this on debug:                 var aux = Request;
                var aux2 = Request.Params;
                var aux3 = Request.Params.AllKeys; And none of this was null

Comment: I updated my answer a little before your comment. Check out 'l' which is one of your keys.

Comment: @qadesh i agree with Ian your l value is probably null for the check

Comment: I updated my question a little before your update LOL. And yes, somehow there's a null key. But... WTF!?(sorry for the words) This list is autofilled I can't add/modify/delete any of it... Any idea how can I manage this?

Comment: Kinda a separate question, but can you provide some details on how it's auto-filled? Somewhere you must have a null key getting through. You might be able to figure out where (if you're binding to a datasource) by looking at the next/previous keys by suppressing the exception.

Comment: @qadesh: For the benefit of other users I'd be tempted to mark this as the answer (as it deals with the original question in the post) and then upvote Josh's answer instead as it's good but doesn't explain the the problem for anyone else reading the post and looking for a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Request.Params or  `"stringImLookingFor"` (if it's a variable, not constant) is not null?

Comment: "stringImLookingFor" is a constant. And Request.Params has 70 values inside... So not null either :S

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Thx to @Ian!

I had a null key on Request.Params.AllKeys. By now my solution is:

List ParamsList = Request.Params.AllKeys.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)).ToList();

ParamsList.Any(l => l.Contains("CourseName"))

If anyone finds something nicer, tell me please : )

Comment: I'd recommend finding the cause of the problem. Additionally you can do (l => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l) && l.Contains("CourseName")) doing it in one line. If my answer was useful enough then please mark it as accepted :) Thanks.

Comment: @Ian, if you want it to be accepted, make an answer, not comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution could potentially be very inefficient.

```
List ParamsList = Request.Params.AllKeys.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)).ToList();
ParamsList.Any(l => l.Contains("CourseName"));
```

The above requires iterating over the entire collection to produce a new list, and then iterating over that new list until you find the element that matches. The below should be a little better:

```
Request.Params.AllKeys
    .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
    .Any(l => l.Contains("CourseName");
```

That will filter our any null values before it hits the call to `Any`. It will also mean that there is only one iteration through the collection, and will stop as soon as the course is found.